# Different encoding in python and ruby

Tags: python, ruby, encoding, ord

I am trying to mimic Rubys .bytesize string function in Python. However I am having an issue with certain characters e.g. "‘"

In Ruby

```
"‘".bytesize returns 3
"‘".bytes returns [226, 128, 152]
```

In Python

```
ord("‘") returns 8216
len(ord("‘")) returns 1
```

What is the difference in encoding between the two languages? This is further confused with different online convertors providing similarly contrasting results. For example - http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/ produces the same results as Ruby does, whereas https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter produces the same results as Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with UTF-8 string, forget about bytes.

[`String#codepoints`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-codepoints) will return the codepoints array, [`String#length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-length) returns the length of the UTF-8 string:

```
"‘".codepoints #⇒ [8216]
"‘".length     #⇒ 1
```

[`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) provides the low-level access to the graphemas.

```
"‘".unpack "U+"
```

---

Whether you still want to get an access to *bytes*, you might:

```
"‘".unpack "C*"
#⇒ [226, 128, 152]
```

To get bytes for the UTF-8 symbol in python, one might use `bytes`:

```
>>> chars = bytes("‘".encode("utf8"))
>>> chars
#⇒ b'\xe2\x80\x98'
>>> len(chars)
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: So in Ruby when "‘".bytes #=> [226, 128, 152] what is this actually returning, what encoding is this getting the bytes for?

Comment: It is getting bytes for not single-byte encoding UTF-8.

Comment: How would I replicate that effect in Python? Edit: nevermind seen your most recent edition and it works perfectly, thankyou!

Comment: If you want to replicate this behaviour in python, use `bytes` passing the string as a parameter. I can not think of any reason of doing that, though, save for very low-level binary transfers, like TCP level protocol implementation, but I bet this is not you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would suggest you to start with reading about what string encoding is in general.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two UTF-8 strings in

Python 3:

```
>>> s1
'è'
>>> s2
'è'
```

and Ruby:

```
> s1
=> "è"
> s2
=> "è"
```

While those string all *look* the same, they are not:

```
>>> s1==s2
False

> s1==s2
=> false
```

That is because while it is the same [grapheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) they are actually two different byte strings:

```
>>> [[s, len(s), list(s)] for s in (s1,s2)]
[['è', 1, ['è']], ['è', 2, ['e', '̀']]]
> [s1,s2].map {|s| [s, s.length, s.each_char.to_a]}
=> [["è", 1, ["è"]], ["è", 2, ["e", "̀"]]]
```

As you can see, there are multiple ways to make up a single grapheme, or what we would call characters. If you have composing characters, like `'̀'` in `s2`, the length of the string, by bytes, will be different than you might expect:

```
> s1.length==s2.length
=> false
```

In Ruby, you can use the `\X` regex to scan for bytes or groups of bytes that compose a single grapheme:

```
> s2.scan(/\X/)
=> ["è"]
```

Then their logical length will be the same:

```
> s1.scan(/\X/).length==s2.scan(/\X/).length
=> true
```

Or, normalize the string:

You can also [normalize](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize) the s2 string in Ruby to combine the two bytes into a single equivalent grapheme:

```
> s2.unicode_normalize.length==s1.length
=> true
```

In Python, you would either use `unicodedate` to normalize:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s2) == s1
True
>>> len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s2)) == len(s1)
True
```

Or install and use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) that supports `\X`. (The `re` module does not support `\X`)

If what you really want in the same byte-by-byte approach in Python as Ruby, you might do:

```
>>> [int(e) for e in bytes("‘".encode('utf-8'))]
[226, 128, 152]
> "‘".bytes
=> [226, 128, 152]
```

But I am not sure what you intend to do with that...

Or if you want the same `ord` value:

```
>>> ord("‘")
8216
> "‘".ord
=> 8216
```